# Reinforcement Learning where every state is terminal

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

My question is not related to the implementation of Reinforcement Learning, but to understand the concept of RL when every state is a terminal state.

I'll give an example: A robot is learning to play soccer, just shooting. The reward is the distance between the ball and the goalpost after it shoots for the goal. The state is an array of multiple features, and the action is an array with the three-dimensional force.

If we considered episodic RL, I feel like the approach doesn't make sense. Indeed, the robot shoots and the reward is given: each episode is a terminal episode. It doesn't make sense to pass the next state to the system since the algorithm doesn't care about it to optimize the reward - in this case, I would use an Actor-Critic approach to handle continuous state and action space. Someone might argue that a different supervised learning approach, such as a Deep Neural Network, might work better. But I am not sure since in that case, the algorithm would not be able to achieve good results with input far from the training set. As far as I saw, RL is able to generalize better for this context.

The question is: is RL a valid methodology for this problem, and how are terminal states managed in this case? Are you aware of similar examples in literature?

Comment: Hi, did you find any suitable algorithm to solve it? I have an exact same problem. Really appreciate if you have any more info on the solution

Comment: @corvo As other users said, RL tries to solve a problem that this specific setting doesn't have: reward attribution. If every state is terminal, it doesn't make sense to learn a policy that maps state to actions in order to maximize a cumulative expected reward, since the cumulative expected reward is just the episodic reward.

Comment: Yeah, that must be it for not being able to use RL. Any other algorithms you'd recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reinforcement Learning solves a problem you don't have

The main difficulty targeted by RL approaches is regarding reward attribution to much earlier actions, figuring out ways how to deal with the (common) complication where there's no explicit feedback about what (and when) you did right or wrong. You don't have this problem - you have an immediate reward that's directly attributable to the action.

Basic supervised learning approaches would work well with that, and there's no reason to involve the reinforcement learning "machinery".

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The approach I am analyzing (just for educational purpose) is supervised learning where I backpropagate the distance of the ball and the target after it shoots for the goal (let's say I backpropagate what would have been the reward in RL). This distance, which I want to minimize, would act as the loss. Do you consider this a valid approach?

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood correctly your question, the problem you are describing is known in the literature as **Contextual Bandits**. In such a case, you have a set of states and the agent recives a reward after performing one action. This problems are closely related with Reinforcement Learning, but they have some particular features that are exploited to design specific algorithms.

The following figure, extracted from an [Arthur Juliani's post](https://medium.com/emergent-future/simple-reinforcement-learning-with-tensorflow-part-1-5-contextual-bandits-bff01d1aad9c), shows the main difference between Multi-armed Bandit, Contextual Bandit and Reinforcement Learning problems:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly the use case I am describing. Thank you for pointing this out, I didn't know how this problem was characterized in the literature.

Comment: You are welcome! Yes, the literature is huge and sometimes it's difficult to find the right "keywords". BTW, if this answers your question, don't forget to accept the response.

Answer (score 1):

In episodic RL there is no next state, it is just black box (BB) optimization. You case is **contextual** BB as you have also a state (the ball position, I guess). You can use policy gradient (like [NES](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume15/wierstra14a/wierstra14a.pdf) or [PGPE](http://people.idsia.ch/~juergen/icann2008sehnke.pdf)), policy search ([here](https://spiral.imperial.ac.uk/bitstream/10044/1/12051/7/fnt_corrected_2014-8-22.pdf) is a good survey), evolutionary ([CMA-ES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMA-ES)) or hybrid. They differ on how the update is performed, but they all are reward-agnostic, i.e., they don't know the reward function but just receive reward values.

They all share the same approach:

- You have an initial policy (aka search distribution),
- See the features and feed them to the policy, which will give you "the action" (in your case: draw the control parameters of the robot, then shoot),
- See the reward,
- Repeat and collect data `(features, action, reward)`,
- Update policy until you learn the robot controller that is able to always hit the ball at any position.

**EDIT**

Since you don't have a next state, your problem is kinda a regression problem, but you don't know the optimal target (optimal action = optimal robot controller). Instead, you draw some target and slowly fit to the best ones (slowly, like with gradient descent, because there may be better ones that you still have to explore).

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. I was considering to use DDPG, but I am having some trouble in the implementation, so I will study the approaches you suggested. One question: these methods are able to give continuous actions (the angle of the shot), or they are used for discrete space?

Comment: They work with both discrete and continuous spaces.
Using DDPG does not make sense because you don't have a next state, thus you don't have a TD error `delta = Q(s',a') + gamma*r - Q(s,a)`. I have edited my answer to add some details.